# installing express on windows issues

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am trying to install express framework for node on my Windows system, it always stops with an error:

> info it worked if it ends with ok
>   verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe',
>   verbose cli   'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',        verbose cli
>   'install',               verbose cli   '-g',             verbose cli
>   'express' ]            info using npm@1.1.0-3            info using
>   node@v0.6.9             verbose config file C:\Users\kpatil.npmrc
>   verbose config file C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\etc\npmrc
>   verbose config file C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc             verbose mkdir done:
>   C:\Users\kpatil\AppData\Roaming\npm 755               verbose cache
>   add [ 'express', null ]                  silly cache add: name, spec,
>   args [ undefined, 'express', [ 'express', null ] ]
>   verbose parsed url { pathname: 'express', path: 'express', href:
>   'express' }              verbose addNamed [ 'express', '' ]
>   verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]                silly name, range,
>   hasData [ 'express', '', false ]              verbose raw, before any
>   munging express               verbose url resolving [
>   'http://registry.npmjs.org/', './express' ]
>   verbose url resolved http://registry.npmjs.org/express       http GET
>   http://registry.npmjs.org/express          ERR! Error: failed to fetch
>   from registry: express            ERR!     at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\npm-registry-client\get.js:139:12
>   ERR!     at cb (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\npm-registry-client\request.js:32:9)
>   ERR!     at Request._callback (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\npm-registry-client\request.js:137:18)
>   ERR!     at Request.callback (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\main.js:109:22)
>   ERR!     at Request. (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\main.js:198:58)
>   ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)               ERR!     at
>   ClientRequest. (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\main.js:195:10)
>   ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)                 ERR! 
>   at Socket. (http.js:1134:11)                      ERR!
>   at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Can you connect to http://registry.npmjs.org/express in a browser?

Comment: No.. tried setting up the proxy too but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use the advice from Microsoft:

> Try npm cache clean first.
>
> If that doesn’t fix things, take a look in %APPDATA%\npm-cache,
>
> or if you’re using PowerShell, $env:APPDATA\npm-cache.

If that doesn't work, use the URI template pattern of the registry JSON to do it manually:

- Open https://registry.npmjs.org/express/latest in a browser or text editor
- Search for `tgz`
- Copy that URL
- Paste it into the location bar in a browser to download it
- Unpack the file using 7zip
- Copy the npm files to the same path as node

**References**

- [How to fix Node.js NPM Permission Problems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt-harrington/archive/2012/02/23/how-to-fix-node-js-npm-permission-problems.aspx)
- [Install Node.JS and NPM on Windows](http://www.hacksparrow.com/install-node-js-and-npm-on-windows.html)